# CSS - Styles conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

In my current project I use vendor javascript plugin. And it has it's own css. But when I add Foundation, it breaks this plugin's appearance.
Without Foundation:
[image: Without Foundation]

With Foundation:
[image: With Foundation]

How can I fix it? Am I able to ignore styles, other than it's own specific style, on the plugin object?

**UPDATE**

My css declaration list:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/schedule-style.css" />
```

The plugin: http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Simple-Daily-Schedule-Plugin-with-jQuery-and-jQuery-UI-Schedule.html

Comment: Ensure that the link for Foundation CSS is before the link to the plugin CSS?

Comment: You can be more specific with your styles ensuring that you are targetting specific elements i.e. #myClass p instead of generic selectors

Comment: @jeff the plugin css file use the id selector to define style.

Comment: Add the css of the Library/foundation before your own. Custom style class names should be different from ones mentioned in the lib. Add your style by class names and not apply it directly on HTML elements. Read more about CSS preferences. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: @Stu added the css declaration list. Actualy, custom.css doesn't contain anything, that could cause the problem,

Comment: Add <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script> see how to use it? section of http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Simple-Daily-Schedule-Plugin-with-jQuery-and-jQuery-UI-Schedule.html

Comment: @Stu they are already there. And the plugin works correctly.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your code or better share it on JSFiddle?

Comment: @Stu it's hard to recreate the page on JSFiddle now, I'll try later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display problems you're seeing are due Foundation's use of `box-sizing: inherit`.

You can override this for `#schedule` by adding a new rule in your custom stylesheet:

```
#schedule {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```